# The power series $\sum_0^\infty2^{-n}z^{2n}$ converges, if

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

The power series $\sum_0^\infty2^{-n}z^{2n}$ converges, if

a) |$z$| $\le$ 2.

b) |$z$| $<$ 2.

c) |$z$| $\le$ $\sqrt{2}$.

d) |$z$| $<$ $\sqrt{2}$.

Please anyone give me the answer. I think option (c) is the correct.

Comment: Since the answers already solved it, think about why $|z| \leq \sqrt2$ can't be correct; specifically, what happens if $z = \sqrt2$?

Comment: If $z$=$\sqrt{2}$, the sum will be infinity, i.e, series will be diverges.

Answer (score 4):

$a_n = (\dfrac{z^2}{2})^n$. This is a geometric series, so it converges iff $|\dfrac{z^2}{2}| < 1$, so $|z| < \sqrt{2}$. Thus $d$. is the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I understood I was wrong, option (c) will be not, (d) is correct.